# Inner template class as template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I have a class that takes a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename> class F>
class A {};
```

And another templated class with an inner templated class:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
  public:
    template <typename U>
    class C {};
};
```

I want to be able to use `C` as the template template parameter for `A` in a templated context:

```
template <typename T>
using D = A<B<T>::C>;
```

However, this results in an error message:

"template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template"

I am assuming that I am missing some magic incantation of `typename` and `template` in the declaration of `D`, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me and the error message isn't particularly useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message complains that `B<T>::C` is not a template, thus it doesn't match the template template parameter of `A`.

You need to use [`template`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) keyword to tell the compiler that the [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) `B<T>::C` (which depends on the template parameter `T`) **is** a template.

```
template <typename T>
using D = A<B<T>::template C>;
//                ~~~~~~~~
```